# Logging errors with restrserve

Tags: r, restrserve

I am currently creating a REST API with restrserve.
While trying to add a logger to my application I ran into this problem.
By setting the log level as: `application$logger$set_log_level("error")`,
my console output on error has a JSON structure like:

```
{
   "timestamp":"2020-09-22 18:25:37.425642",
   "level":"ERROR",
   "name":"Application",
   "pid":38662,
   "msg":"",
   "context":{
      "request_id":"alphanumeric string",
      "message":{ here is the description of the error  }
   }
}
```

I set up a printer function following the instructions on the site, but among the available fields (timestamp, level, logger_name, pid, message), "context" is not present,so basically, by just printing the message my logs are empty files.
This is my printer function:

```
application$logger$set_printer(FUN = function(timestamp, level, logger_name, pid, message, ...){
    write(message, file = paste("/Log/Monitor_", pid,
          timestamp, ".txt", sep = ""))
   # attempting to print "context" raises an error!

})
```

Is there a way to print the "context" field present in the console output to a file?

Thanks in advance, any suggestions would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good idea to take a look to the [source](https://github.com/rexyai/RestRserve/blob/d17808d2afbf27bf53a0621246d65a9597d3369d/R/logging.R#L61). There is extra `...` argument where context is passed.
Generally it is advisable to use [lgr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lgr/index.html) package for user-level logging.